# Simple use of log

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am struggling to see how we can go from the first expression to the second:

$$\begin{align}
2\log_3 12 - 4\log_3 6 &= \log_3 \left ( \frac{4^2 \cdot 3^2}{2^4 \cdot 3^4} \right )\\
&= \log_3 (3^{-2}) = -2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that
\[ \log_{b}(x^{n})=n\log_{b}(x) \]
\[ \log_{b}(x)-\log_{b}(y)=\log_{b}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \]
Here are the steps
\[
2\log_{3} 12 - 4\log_{3} 6 = 2\log_{3} (4\cdot 3) - 4\log_{3} (2\cdot 3) 
\]
\[
=\log_{3} (4\cdot 3)^{2} - \log_{3} (2\cdot 3)^{4} = \log_{3} (4^{2}\cdot 3^{2}) - \log_{3} (2^{4}\cdot 3^{4})
\]
\[
= \log_{3} \frac{4^{2}\cdot 3^{2}}{2^{4}\cdot 3^{4}} = \log_{3} \frac{16}{16\cdot 3^{2}}=\log_{3} \frac{1}{3^{2}}=\log_{3} 3^{-2}=-2\log_{3} 3 = -2
\]

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Use $$\log a+\log b=\log(ab)$$  and $$m\log c=\log(c^m)$$

where each logarithm remains defined

**Reference** : [Laws of Logarithms](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Laws_of_Logarithms)

Comment: For the second step, remember that $4^2=(2^2)^2=2^4$

Answer (score 3):

Remember, $$\log ab = \log a + \log b$$

and

$$m\log a=\log a^m.$$

HINT:

$$12^2 = (4\cdot 3)^2=4^2\cdot 3^2.$$

Similarly,

$$6^4 = (2\cdot 3)^4 = 2^4\cdot 3^4$$

I think you can take it from here.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering this and the first hint, made me understand it however there are answer at this page that are in more detail, should I pick the answer that made me understand it at first or should I pick the complete answer and not the hint?

Comment: @ALEXANDER It's entirely up to you. Your question, your answer :-)